# Continuing a Visual Studio 2010 project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, web-applications

I am given a ASP.NET web forms project initially done in Visual Studio 2010 to do some fixes. Is it okay to continue it in Visual Studio 2013? Would there be any problems, like not being able to open it in VS 2010 later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with converting the project from VS2010 to VS2013.

But you are correct in that you won't be able to go back to VS2010.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to clarify that.